# TF101 Android: Image block device via adb

Tags: partitioning, images, android, debug

I have an Asus TF101 tablet running Android ICS. I am trying to image the entire internal flash file system onto my desktop via adb. **The problem is that the image I am obtaining appears to be corrupted:**

On my desktop I am using Ubuntu 12.10:

```
adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/sdk/platform-tools/adb shell su -c "dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0" | pv > mmcblk0.raw
```

I am then trying to use this image with:

```
testdisk mmcblk0.raw
```

Unfortunately testdisk finds only nonsensical partition data even using a deep search. Attempting to list any of the files contained in these admittedly non-sensical partition results in a corrupt filesystem error.

Even when trying to read out only a single partition, e.g.

```
adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/sdk/platform-tools/adb shell su -c "dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p7" | pv > mmcblk0p7.raw
```

the resulting partition image seems corrupted. Trying to mount via a loop device fails with corrupt filesystem errors. Running fsck on the image floods me with non-ending file-system errors.

Any hint on what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I know this topic is old, but this could help someone:
If you can install a modded recovery it would be very useful, dumping with system on is not always a good idea. Then try this:

```
adb shell "dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0" | dd of=mmcblk0
```

The filesystem should be unmounted when executing a dump for best results.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, the shell on the Android side is converting LF to CR-LF -- [hex 0A to 0D 0A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578416/read-binary-stdout-data-from-adb-shell). Various workarounds are to undo the change by streaming through `sed` or `perl`, processing the file after, or installing `stty` on the Android device and using [`stty raw`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689511/transferring-binary-data-over-adb-shell-ie-fast-file-transfer-using-tar) as part of the `adb shell` command.

Answer (score 0):

Must to use twin quotes. (With Gingerbread 2.3.4)

```
adb shell 'su -c "dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0"' | dd of=data.raw
```