# Solve this hex riddle! - What went wrong with my output redirection?

Tags: linux, android, redirection, disk-image, hexdump

Following on from my question [TF101 Android: Image block device via adb](https://superuser.com/questions/728734/tf101-android-image-block-device-via-adb) in which I tried unsuccessfully to save a raw image of a block device by output redirection, this question tries to determine what went wrong.

**Situation**:

A block device on a android device was read out twice.

1. Once (unsuccessfully) with: adb shell su -c "dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0p7" | pv > faulty.raw
2. Once (successfully) not with output redirection but by using netcat resulting in successful.raw

The file system is ext4. The raw image files were compared with the following command:

```
cmp -l faulty.raw successful.raw | mawk 'function oct2dec(oct,     dec) {for (i = 1; i <= length(oct); i++) {dec *= 8; dec += substr(oct, i, 1)}; return dec} {printf "%08X %02X %02X\n", $1, oct2dec($2), oct2dec($3)}' | head -n 100
```

The resulting output shows only the differences in the two files in hex format. The first column is the file offset, the second column gives the value in the faulty image and the third column the value in the sucessful image.

**Can anybody see what went wrong with the command using output redirection from this binary comparison?** Also: can the (faulty) image be recovered by applying some correction? The file sizes are comparable

```
0000040D AE 37
0000040E 5D 8A
0000040F 22 2A
00000411 1D BE
00000412 03 01
0000042D 2B 30
0000042E AD 47
0000042F 1B 20
00000431 2B 30
00000432 AD 47
00000433 1B 20
00000435 B7 B9
00000490 0D 3D
00000491 2E 1E
00000493 30 D8
00000494 7B ED
00000495 56 44
00000498 4B 8B
00000499 62 59
0000049B 20 C0
0000049C 4D 6B
0000049D 2C BF
000004A0 0D 3D
000004A1 2E 1E
000004A3 68 10
000004A4 B6 49
000004A5 61 59
000004A8 4B 8B
000004A9 62 59
000004BB E0 C0
000004BC 16 46
000004BD AD 82
000004C3 20 C0
000004C4 4D 6B
000004C5 2C BF
000004E9 58 00
000004EA 40 00
000004EB 17 00
0000050D 0D 0A
0000050E 0D F3
0000050F 0A 02
00000510 F3 00
00000511 02 03
00000513 03 00
0000051D 00 FA
0000051E 00 79
0000051F FA 00
00000520 79 00
00000521 00 05
00000522 00 06
00000523 05 00
00000524 06 00
00000525 00 FA
00000526 00 79
00000527 FA 00
00000528 79 00
00000529 00 06
0000052A 00 06
0000052B 06 00
0000052C 06 00
0000052D 00 05
0000052E 00 86
0000052F 05 00
00000530 86 00
0000055D 00 1C
00000561 1C 02
00000563 02 00
00000579 00 14
0000057A 00 D2
0000057B 50 63
0000057C 4F 12
0000057D 54 00
0000057E 12 00
00001001 00 03
00001002 00 04
00001003 03 00
00001004 04 00
00001005 00 04
00001006 00 04
00001007 04 00
00001008 04 00
00001009 00 05
0000100A 00 04
0000100B 05 00
0000100C 04 00
0000100F 00 F6
00001010 00 1F
00001011 F6 01
00001012 1F 00
00001013 01 04
00001015 04 00
00001021 00 03
00001022 00 84
00001023 03 00
00001024 84 00
00001025 00 04
00001026 00 84
00001027 04 00
00001028 84 00
00001029 00 05
```

**Working theory**

Could this possibly be due to a codepage mismatch between the android device and the device running adb? I am thinking this for two reasons:

1. The matching bytes are often "00" which I believe is conserved in different code pages.
2. There appears to be a surprising number of direct conversions byte1 -> byte2. Too many to be entirely due to chance.

Examples:

- 20 -> C0  (see 0000049B and 000004C3)
- 62 -> 59  (see 00000499 and 000004A9)
- 0D -> 3D  (see 00000490 and 000004A0 but different at 0000050D and 0000050E)
- 1B -> 20  (see 0000042F and 00000433)
- 2B -> 30  (see 0000042D and 00000431)
- 2C -> BF  (see 0000049D and 000004C5)
- 2E -> 1E  (see 00000491 and 000004A1)
- 4B -> 8B  (see 00000498 and 000004A8)
- 4D -> 6B  (see 0000049C and 000004C4)
- AD -> 47  (see 0000042E abd 00000432 but different at 000004BD)

As you can see, a remarkable consistency. The differences might be due to changes on the block device between the two image file readouts.

Can anybody identify the code page of the first file? (If this theory indeed holds up.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was much simpler than my working theory.

adb was running on a windows machine. It replaced every '\n' character by '\r\r\n'. The file was recovered using the multi-line perl script of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/730437/307551).